# How can I use Cron in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I use a *cron job* file in *CakePHP* for sending GCM messages in particular interval?

Can you suggest any tutorials for this?

I would like to send GCM messages to an Android phone in fixed intervals.

Comment: Cron isn't something you use in PHP. It's a Linux tool.

Comment: I downvoted this question for the lack of research and quality - also it is way to broadly addressed and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a custom data source or maybe transport adapter for the CakeEmail class, I haven't looked much at the GCM spec (your job). Use a cake shell to send the messags in an interval.

You can find the all the info about custom datasources, mail transports and shells (including cron jobs) here:

- CakePHP Book http://book.cakephp.org/
- Shells http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html
- Creating a shell http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell
- **Shells and Cronjobs** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

The last link contains the info how to set up a cron job with cakephp shells.

Comment: how you answer a question that didn't have 2 min research what is Cron Not Corone